# How to change the position of star ratings on a single product page in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, rating, hook-woocommerce

I am currently working on moving the star rating from underneath add to cart button to below the single product title position.

[image: Original pic].

For that, I am using hooks in my child theme's function.php file:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 6 );
```

But I get the strange result, look at it yourself

[image: Result]

Good news is that I have the second rating, but why is the remove_action not removing the original star rating? As you can see, now I have two duplicate star ratings.

Here is the link to the website [>>>](http://dev.studiopence.com/glenwood/product/15-piece-signature-truffle-collection/)

Answer (score 4):

You can move the star rating from underneath add to cart button to below the single product title -

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );

add_action('init', 'add_new_star_rating');
    function add_new_star_rating()
    {
      add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 6 );
    }
```

use this code in **function.php** file.